# Accessing a structure parameter from a callback function using ctypes

Tags: python, macos, callback, ctypes, coremidi

I am using the CoreMIDI functions from MacOSX to access a MIDI device in my computer. Furthermore, I want to do it using Python and ctypes.

In order to do this, I have to create a callback function that will be called whenever a MIDI message is received by my computer. The callback prototype (in C) is:

```
typedef void ( *MIDIReadProc)(
const MIDIPacketList *pktlist,
void *readProcRefCon,
void *srcConnRefCon);
```

MIDIPacketList is defined as:

```
struct MIDIPacketList { 
UInt32 numPackets; 
MIDIPacket packet[1]; 
};
```

MIDIPacket is defined as:

```
struct MIDIPacket { 
MIDITimeStamp timeStamp; 
UInt16 length; 
Byte data[256]; 
};
```

And MIDITimeStamp is defined as:

```
typedef UInt64 MIDITimeStamp;
```

Ok, so my code for defining the callback and the custom structures is the following:

```
MIDITimeStamp = c_ulonglong

class MIDIPacket(Structure):
    _fields_ = [("timeStamp", MIDITimeStamp),
                ("length", c_ushort),
                ("data", c_char_p)]

class MIDIPacketList(Structure):
    _fields_ = [("numPackets", c_uint),
                ("packet", POINTER(MIDIPacket))]

def callback(midi_packet_list, proc_ref, src_ref):
    m_pack_list = midi_packet_list.contents
    packet = m_pack_list.packet.contents
    print packet.length     # This line crashes the program

CALLBACKFUNC = CFUNCTYPE(None, POINTER(MIDIPacketList), c_void_p, c_void_p)
midi_input_callback = CALLBACKFUNC(callback)

# I omitted the MIDI setup code because I don't think it is relevant here

# MIDIInputPortCreate associates the callback function to the midi endpoint and input port
result = core_midi.MIDIInputPortCreate(midi_client, input_port_name, midi_input_callback, None, byref(input_port));
```

I don't know why but I am not being able to access correctly the data pointed by midi_packet_list in the callback function. This should be a pointer to a MIDIPacketList structure, which I dereference with midi_packet_list.contents. Then I try to get the parameter packet[0], which should be a MIDIPacketObject. But when I try to access the MIDIPacket data (packet.length) the program crashes.

I know the callback is being called correctly because when my MIDI device is turned off it is never called, but when the MIDI device is on I can print info on the screen. But I can't access the data from MIDIPacketList, which is the most important part of the callback routine. I need someone to help me to point me out how is the correct way to access this data.

Thanks!

Comment: Eryk, I will try to change the definition of the 'data' variable. I could not test it today because I am away from my MIDI keyboard, but tomorrow I will test it and let you know... Now I realise, probably the function that creates the MIDI Packets must return an error when it tries to use the "c_char_p" pointer to create a buffer and then fails. If I just set "data" to have 256 bytes, which probably is the maximum there will ever be, would it solve the problem of the dynamically sized arrays? What are properties for?

Comment: Thanks so much for your response! The program is not crashing anymore, however I still have to decode the MIDIPacket to see if the data that is coming makes any sense. Anyway, I didn't understand why should I use "MIDIPacket * 1". What does this do? Why is this different than "POINTER(MIDIPacket)"?

Comment: `MIDIPacket * 1` is a length 1 array of packets that's stored as a member of the struct, whereas a pointer is the address of a packet array that could be stored anywhere. If you were to declare that field a pointer, then the first `timeStamp` field would be used as the address.

Comment: Unfortunately the MIDIPacketNext function is, in fact, a macro, defined as `((MIDIPacket *)&(pkt)->data[(pkt)->length])`. So, I have to get a pointer to the memory region `length` bytes from `packet.data`. Do you know how to do this? I couldn't find out how to edit directly the addresses of ctypes pointers...

Comment: Define `MIDIPacket.data` as a `c_ubyte * 1` (don't use `c_char * 1`) and `MIDIPacketList.packet` as a `MIDIPacket * 1`. Then in your callback start at `packet = m_pack_list[0].packet[0]`. To advance to the next packet in a loop, use `packet = cast(byref(packet.data, packet.length), POINTER(MIDIPacket))[0]`.

Comment: To get `data` as a string, you can use `data = string_at(packet.data, packet.length)`, or you could cast it as an array: `data = cast(packet.data, POINTER(c_ubyte * packet.length))[0]`. I'd make this a `property` of the `MIDIPacket` class. Speaking of which, I'd also put the iteration logic in a `MIDIPacketList.__iter__` generator function (i.e. `yield` the next packet).